# Access 2013 SQL, three tables, two using sum wrong results

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, aggregate

Can someone please help me with this issue? I've scoured the Internet looking at dozens of examples, but i just can't find a solution that works.
I am using Access 2013. The problem is that I am trying to make a query that will highlight all part numbers from a supplier that either has customer back orders and/or overdue deliveries.

I am using three tables:

1. *tbl_Inventory_Master* which I require the *part number*, *on hand stock value*, and the *supplier code*.
2. For any back orders I need to join the t*bl_Customer_Back_Order* table as I need the count of *back order lines* and the sum of the *back order quantity*.
3. If the supplier has a late delivery, then I need to add the *tbl_On_Order* table showing the count of *overdue deliveries* and the sum of the *overdue quantities*.

The query is retrieving the data but the returned quantities are double what they should be.

```
SELECT
    I.Inventory_Part_Num, I.Description, I.On_Hand_Stock,
    COUNT (B.Part_Number) AS Back_Order_Count, SUM(B.Back_Order_Qty) as BO_Qty, 
    COUNT(O.Part_Number) AS Late_Deliveries_Count, SUM(O.Order_Qty) AS Late_Qty
FROM (tbl_Inventory_Master AS I   
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_Customer_Back_Order AS B
    ON I.Inventory_Part_Num = B.Part_Number)
LEFT OUTER tbl_On_Order AS O
    ON I.Inventory_Part_Num = O.Part_Number
WHERE
    I.Customer_Code = '274' AND
    O.Due_Date < [ENTER TODAYS DATE IN FORMAT DD/MM/YYYY]
GROUP BY I.Inventory_Part_Num, I.Description, I.On_Hand_Stock
```

For example, for the part number 2022940 I should have 10 *back order lines* and an *overdue quantity* of 43. Instead, the query is returning 20 *back order lines* and an *overdue quantity* sum of 86.

From the on order table I have three orders totaling 144 pieces, instead the query is returning 960.

Can someone please advise, as this is driving me crazy?

Comment: Between not having any sample data and not being a guru in Access, I can't offer a formal answer.  _But_, I'll bet that the solution will be to do some or all of those aggregations in separate subqueries.  Why?  Because you said that things are being duplicated.  This is almost certainly due to the effect of joining when you should not be.

Comment: please provide sqlfiddle with sample of data and expected result

Comment: Build the aggregate queries then join those to tbl_Inventory_Master. Or use domain aggregate functions.

Answer (score 0):

You are joining along unrelated dimensions, so you need to aggregate before joining:

```
SELECT I.Inventory_Part_Num, I.Description, I.On_Hand_Stock,
       B.Back_Order_Count, B.BO_Qty, 
       O.Late_Deliveries_Count, O.Late_Qty
FROM (tbl_Inventory_Master AS I LEFT OUTER JOIN
      (SELECT B.Part_Number, COUNT(*) as Back_Order_Count,
              SUM(B.Back_Order_Qty) as BO_Qty
       FROM tbl_Customer_Back_Order AS B
       GROUP BY B.Part_Number
      ) as B
      ON I.Inventory_Part_Num = B.Part_Number
     ) LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT O.Part_Number, COUNT(O.Part_Number) AS Late_Deliveries_Count,
             SUM(O.Order_Qty) AS Late_Qty
      FROM tbl_On_Order AS O
      WHERE O.Due_Date < [ENTER TODAYS DATE IN FORMAT DD/MM/YYYY]    
      GROUP BY O.Part_Number
      ) as O
    ON I.Inventory_Part_Num = O.Part_Number
WHERE I.Customer_Code = '274';
```

Notice the outer aggregation is no longer needed.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thank you so much for this elegant solution, it works perfectly. I have previously found a lot of very similar answers that nearly worked or gave me errors, possibly due to simple things like Access not liking the 'as' for table aliases. Reading your code i now actually have a much better understanding of the logic. Thanks again for the solution, you are a superstar! Also, thank you to everyone who took the time to read my post and comment. I love this site.